# Brigitte's Repair Pack and Ana's Biotic Grenade?

Tags: overwatch

Brigitte's Repair Pack heals allies for 150 HP. If the ally is fully healed, the remaining healing will be added as armor, with a maximum of 75 HP worth of armor.

Ana's Biotic Grenade, when it hits an enemy, causes damage and prevents healing for a short duration. If it hits an ally, they get 100 HP healing and any healing they receive will be doubled for a short duration.

How do the two interact with each other? What happens if Brigitte tries to heal an ally who was hit by an enemy Ana's Biotic Grenade? What happens if Brigitte heals an ally who was hit by a friendly Ana's Biotic Grenade? I have some guesses, but I'm unable to test it, hence why I ask here.

**Trying to heal an ally hit by an enemy Ana's Biotic Grenade**

1. The ally receives 75 HP worth of armor and no actual healing.
2. Brigitte can't heal her ally at all. Maybe trying to heal said ally causes her to waste her ability and it goes into cooldown, or the ally can't be selected for healing at all.

**Trying to heal an ally hit by a friendly Ana's Biotic Grenade**

1. The ally receives 300 HP. If the ally is fully healed, the remaining healing will be added as armor, but it's still capped at 75 HP worth of armor.
2. The ally receives 300 HP. If the ally is fully healed, the remaining healing will be added as 150 HP worth of armor.

Comment: Can confirm that for the second second bullet point option 1 is true - however as I too an unable to test the first one I can't really post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this in game and it seems that Briggite cannot target her ally under the negative effect of Ana's grenade. Also, Option 1 under the second point is also true.

Source: Tested in game